# Android Kotlin Camera won't start, App Crashes

Tags: android, kotlin

I have started working on an app which starts the permissions and camera after a button is clicked. The first screen will have a button, which when clicked will start the camera (following CameraX tutorial for the second bit). Here is the first screen:

```
class Upload : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload)
            val openUpload = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btncamera)
            openUpload.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, OpenCamera::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

}
```

After the btnCamera above is clicked, the next activity should start:

```
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class OpenCamera : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityOpenCameraBinding

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private var recording: Recording? = null

    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityOpenCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        val activityResultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions())
            { permissions ->
                // Handle Permission granted/rejected
                var permissionGranted = true
                permissions.entries.forEach {
                    if (it.key in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS && !it.value)
                        permissionGranted = false
                }
                if (!permissionGranted) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext,
                        "Permission request denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    startCamera()
                }
            }
        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            fun requestPermissions() {
                activityResultLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
            }
        }

        // Set up the listeners for take photo and video capture buttons
        viewBinding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }
        viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener { captureVideo() }

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {}

    private fun captureVideo() {}

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {}

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf (
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ).apply {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }
            }.toTypedArray()
    }
}
```

After I click the btnCamera from first activity, the app crashes instead of going to the next screen to show me the preview and capture the photo. I am completely new as I come from data science background and trying my hands at App development. I am also not sure about the error as there is no error except for app crashing and starting back from first screen. Any help/guidance will be appreciated. If edit or more information is required, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: It will be better to share your crash logs as well